# nedb - Create databases dynamically

Tags: node.js, express, raspberry-pi, nedb

I have two Temp. Sensors on my Raspberry Pi and I have a node.js Express app. I want to create nedb databases dynamically of an array with sensor objects.

So I have an object with sensors in it:

```
  sensors: [
    {
      name: "Indoor",
      type: 22,
      pin: 21
    },
    {
      name: "Outdoor",
      type: 22,
      pin: 21
    }
  ]};
```

Now I want to create for every Sensor three database:

```
databaseSetup(app.sensors);

function databaseSetup(sensor){
  const dataStore = require('nedb');
  const databaseVariables = [];
  sensor.forEach((sensor) => {
    const live = 'live' + sensor.name;
    const seconds = 'seconds' + sensor.name;
    const hours = 'hours' + sensor.name;
    const test = { 
    live: new dataStore(`./databases/temp/${sensor.name}/live.db`),
    seconds: new dataStore(`./databases/temp/${sensor.name}/seconds.db`),
    hours: new dataStore(`./databases/temp/${sensor.name}/hours.db`) }
    databaseVariables.push(test);
  });
}
```

But this is not working. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you trying to do cause in my mind this is a bad practice. but you can make it dynamic. something like this:

```
const dt = require('nedb');
const db = [];

//USING LOOP and FUNCTION
let list = [{ name: "GasSensor" }, { name: "TempSensor" }];
let index = 0;

//BAD Practice
let setup = () => {
    if (index + 1 > list.length) return;

    let newInstance = new dt({ filename: 'nodejs/data/nedb_' + list[index].name, autoload: true });

    console.log("Working on index " + (index + 1));

    newInstance.loadDatabase((err) => {
        if (err) {
            //...
        } else {
            db.push(newInstance);
        }

        index++;
        setup();
    });
}

setup();
```

And also with API:

```
const exp = require("express");
const app = exp();
const dt = require('nedb');
const db = [];

app.get("/make/db/:name", (q, r) => {
    //BAD PRACTICE
    //JUST FOR TEST
    let newInstance = new dt({ filename: 'nodejs/data/nedb_' + q.params.name, autoload: true });

    newInstance.loadDatabase((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err + "");
            r.send("ERROR");
        }
        else {
            db.push(newInstance);
            console.log("Database is loaded");
            r.send("NEW DB CREATED");
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

[image]

[image]